# How to stop a Text in a GridView from overflowing

Tags: flutter

I have a GridView with a Text widget with very long text which softWraps. But if the text is too long, it flows out of the GridView and is not cropped. I tried to wrap in into several Layout Widgets, but none worked.

E.g. FittedBox does not work because then the Text does not softWrap.

This is an example of the GridView:

```
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
      childAspectRatio: 3,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text("$index: Das ist ein langer Text, der hoffentlich auf viele Zeilen umbricht, aber sonst keinen großen Sinn ergibt");
    },
),
```

What could do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the Text widget in a `Clipper`

```
return ClipRect(
  child: Text("$index: Das ist ein langer Text, der hoffentlich auf viele Zeilen umbricht, aber sonst keinen großen Sinn ergibt")
);
```

Comment: thanx, I didn't know that Widget. What an easy solution!